# How to sort dynamically added data in Sencha grid

Tags: grid, extjs

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/restful/restful.html
2. Sort data by ID column
3. Add row
4. The row will be at top of grid but it can be at bottom

The question: how to sort dynamically added data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newly added row is added to the store, see store.insert() in the sample code:

```
 dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
            text: 'Add',
            iconCls: 'icon-add',
            handler: function(){
                // empty record
                store.insert(0, new Person());
                rowEditing.startEdit(0, 0);
            }
        }, '-', {
            text: 'Delete',
            iconCls: 'icon-delete',
            handler: function(){
                var selection = grid.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                if (selection) {
                    store.remove(selection);
                }
            }
        }]
    }]
```

Then it is 'edited' with real values and the store record is updated accordingly.

Maybe all you have to do is to call

```
store.sort('email', 'ASC');
```

But refreshing the grid view might be enough, since after all you already ask it to be sorted:

```
grid.getView().refresh();
```